# Why doesn't the intent of the button work

Tags: java, android

In my Code I have an Intent to an other Activity but when I use my Phone to test it nothing appears. The program doesn't crashes or something like that. It simply does nothing. I have another Intent and this works perfectly. I don't know what the problem is.

I am using the `onClick` feature on the xml file

On the Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Object TextView;
    int eggcounter;
    Button b1;

    android.widget.TextView textClicks;
    private Object SafeBrowsingResponse;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button b1 = findViewById(R.id.b1);

        eggcounter = 100;
        final ImageButton ImgButton = findViewById(R.id.eggBtn);

        ImgButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        eggcounter = eggcounter - 1;
                        updateEgg();
                        if (eggcounter < 80) {
                            ImgButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.egg_2);
                            if (eggcounter < 60){
                                ImgButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.egg_3);
                                if (eggcounter < 40) {
                                    ImgButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.egg_4);
                                    if (eggcounter < 15) {                                        ImgButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.egg_5);
                                        if (eggcounter <= 0) {
                                            b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                            ImgButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.egg_ende);
                                            b1.setOnClickListener(
                                                    new View.OnClickListener() {

                                                        public void onClick(View view) {

                                                        }
                                                    }
                                            );

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void updateEgg() {
        textClicks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScore);
        textClicks.setText(eggcounter + " ");
    }

    public void backstartseite(View view) {
        Intent back = new Intent(this, Startseite.class);
        startActivity(back);
    }

    public void ende (View view) {
        Intent e = new Intent(this, Ende.class);
        startActivity(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are never calling `backStartSeite` or `ende` therefore no `Intent` fires.

Also don't set the `onClickListener` of `b1` inside another `onClickListener` (your listener for `b1` will only be able to handle click events once the other button has been clicked already - this would confuse users).

If you want your `Intent` to work, call either `startSeite` or `ende` in the outer `onClickListener`.